# How to prevent rounding of numbers when using toFixed method

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, math, decimal

I am trying to figure out how to prevent rounding of numbers when it comes to decimal precisions. I am currently using the `.toFixed(2)` method to only display two decimal places after the decimal but it is also rounding this figure. For example, if I had a number 19.528 the method Number(19.528)`.toFixed(2)` will yield 19.53 instead of displaying the value 19.52 . Is there anyway or other method to take care of it so that the number does not round?

Comment: Number(num.toString().slice(0, (num.toString().indexOf("."))+3))

Comment: [MDN: math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) - the trick is to multiply by 100 first the divide by 100 to get the 2 dp.